# How can use Navigator with isSelected by flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, setstate

[image]

[image]

Relating to isSelected and Navigator, how can I use these function together?

Now I have some error happened...

add_page.dart

```
class _AddPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override   State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AddPage();

}
```

main.dart

```
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPage(model),
              ),
            );
          },
```

Comment: may i ask what is your goal by doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the `MainModel model` to your `Addpage` class, you could just pass it as such:

```dart
class AddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel model;

  const AddPage(this.model);

  @override
  _AddPageState createState() => _AddPageState();
}

class _AddPageState extends State<AddPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Your widget tree
    // ...

  }
}
```

But you could just push the `AddPage` screen as you did, and retrieve the `MainModel` model with a Consumer from your context, as you already did.